# Ignoring redefined label

Tags: cross-referencing

How can I make LaTeX ignore a `\label` that is re-used? That is, if I define a label twice, and then cross-reference it, I would like the reference to indicate the first definition of the label.

For example, in this MWE:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    x^2=2 \label{l1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    x^2=3 \label{l1}
\end{equation}
See the equation in \eqref{l1}
\end{document}
```

Then I would like the sentence to read '... in (1)' and not '... in (2)'.

Comment: You get a warning about a duplicate label. Why would you want the same label in two places?

Comment: Why don't change it to `l2` or `foo`? You have two different (however very simple equations in that example), so they should be labelled differently. The use of labels is to be unique!

Comment: You are both right, but I have some piece of latex code that copies  replicates my text (for documentation purposes), and I would like only the first time to 'count'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how you would label different equations with the same `\label`. However, you have to redefine the way the check is performed during the reading of the `.aux` file in order to remove both the warnings and the redefinition of an already-used `\label`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{%
  \@ifundefined{#1@#2}
    {\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}
    {\gdef\@multiplelabels{}}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    x^2=2 \label{l1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    x^2=3 \label{l1}
\end{equation}
See the equation in \eqref{l1}.
\end{document}
```